# org schedule entry when another transitions to DONE

Tags: org-mode

Is there a mechanism to specify that a todo entry should be scheduled after some other Todo entry transitions to DONE? something like `schedule 2d after completion of some other TODO entry or event`. this is much like how [repeated tasks](https://orgmode.org/manual/Repeated-tasks.html) can be automatically rescheduled after transitioning to Done state.

I believe this can be implemented by keeping (id and schedule metadata) pair for each task of interest in the master task. the master task would be the task whose transition to the DONE state is going to be used as a hook to schedule tasks. Then on the hook of when the master task transitions to the Done state, schedule appropriately. It would be nice if this info can also be kept track of in the target tasks that are to be scheduled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried it yet but I think org-edna may be a solution.

You can specify conditions that must exist before a task is set to DONE, and actions to take once it is.

https://www.nongnu.org/org-edna-el/

There is an earlier package called org-depend, described here:

https://karl-voit.at/2016/12/18/org-depend/

Comment: ah, org-edna is cool. So this would be with using an outline path `:TRIGGER: olp("test.org" "path/to/heading") scheduled!(“++2d”)`. There are many more finders like olp.